# Error in cURL request: Magento 2 error on admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, dashboard, curl-request

i need urgent help, i am getting curl request error when i go to Stores->configuration in magento admin panel. I am using magenot 2.4
Please can anyone advice what i can do to resolve this?
https://prnt.sc/_9Vi_ayLw3jC

Comment: Hi there, from the provided screenshot, my guess is that you have installed a local setup of a project, but a third-party module is installed in a vendor ("codsicle") which is looking for a host using CURL, and that host it is not accepting or some other error which is not handled by my guess, try disabling that module and the modules which is dependent on to confirm whether that is causing the issue, and please reply if this was found useful. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i have taken backup from live and setup dev environment. The code is same at both the places, but this is giving error only on developer mode. Its a laminas http module which comes with magento. How can i disable it?

Comment: "Could not resolve host:" mean something is blocked. This could cause by (1) no internet connection, (2) block by a  firewall, or (3) DNS for the domain is not set up. Can you ping feed.migrationmagento.com in your dev environment... you may need to add an entry into your host file with the IP address of the server